# css inline-block image list slider

Tags: html, slider, css

I have a prototype of a image slider. Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4v0hsem1)!

```
<div style="display:block;border:1px solid red;">
<ul style="margin:0px; padding: 0px ;white-space:nowrap; ">
    <li style="display: inline-block;">
        <div style="width:100px;height:100px;text-align: center;border:1px solid black;">A</div>    
    </li>

    <li style="display: inline-block;">
        <div style="width:300px;height:100px;text-align: center;border:1px solid black;">B</div>    
    </li>

    <li style="display: inline-block;">
        <div style="width:450px;height:100px;text-align: center;border:1px solid black;">C</div>    
    </li>

</ul>
```

Unfortunately I have a problem the image are getting truncated because it exceeds its parent width. Is it possible to display without getting it truncated. Any tips or sample works, that I can refer to. Thanks!

Comment: can you create a fiddle

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1** : You can make the parent container overflow: auto or overflow-x: scroll

**Solution 2:** You can, instead of calling the image inline, you can have them as a background image and show some portion of it. You can try playing around image > width:100% or  background-size:cover in css